# Firebase adding new child under certain unique push ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to achieve this:

```
households {
    householdID1 : {
        address : "BLK 16, Woodlands Street"
        accounts : {
            accountID1 : true,
            accountID2 : true,
        }
    }
}
```

But when I tried to insert, it becomes like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 var householdRef = firebase.database().ref('households');

var householdData = {
    address : "Blk 164"
}

householdRef.push(householdData);
var householdKey = householdRef.key;
console.log(householdKey);

var query = firebase.database().ref('accounts').orderByChild('email').equalTo('gab@gmail.com');
query.once( 'value', data => {
    data.forEach(userSnapshot => {
        let userKey = userSnapshot.key;
        console.log('userKey ' + userKey);

        firebase.database().ref('households').child(householdKey).child('accounts').push().set({
          userKey : true,
        }), (error) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
          }else{
            // Success
          }
        }
    });
});
```

After I obtained the householdKey, I tried to add new nested child under that particular householdKey child. I first loop thru accounts record to find the unique ID for account, then I proceed to add. But it ends up become like this picture above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `push()` function, firebase generates a new key for the child.

I can't debug but i think that this is the solution:

```
var householdRef = firebase.database().ref('households');

var householdData = {
  address : "Blk 164",
};

householdRef.push(householdData);
var householdKey = householdRef.key;

var query = firebase.database().ref('accounts').orderByChild('email').equalTo('gab@gmail.com');
query.once( 'value', data => {
    data.forEach(userSnapshot => {
        let userKey = userSnapshot.key;

        firebase.database().ref('households').child(householdKey).child('accounts').update({
          [userKey] : true,
        }), (error) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
          }else{
            // Success
          }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It works! So what's the difference between push() and update() and also the [] for userKey?

Comment: If you use the push() function, firebase generates a new key for the child. With [] you can set a key from a variable.

Comment: Is there anyway to let the userKey becomes public? Because I would like to use it outside the for loop to update another child

Comment: of course, you can retrieve all the user uid and then you can upgrade your children.

Comment: Hey do you mind to take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407374/firebase-retrieve-data-under-certain-child