# Firebase retrieve data under certain child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, nosql

I was having some trouble when trying to retrieve from firebase. Here is my firebase structure:

What I tried to do is firstly, I wanted to get list of receiptItemID in the first picture. Then, after I get the IDs, for each ID, I wanted to get its quantity and type. After that, I will store them into array and perform some sorting.

Here is my code:

```
var query = firebase.database().ref('');
                  query.once( 'value', data => {
                      data.forEach(subtypeSnapshot => {
                        var itemKey = subtypeSnapshot.key;

                        var query = firebase.database().ref('').child(itemKey);

                        });
                  });
                });
```

I managed to get the itemKey. However, when I tried to get the details of each receiptItem by the `console.log` that part, it prints out undefined for both. Any ideas on how to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the forEach cycle, it's one level too deep. Instead, use the 'data' argument directly. This new callback should work:

```
  var itemDetail = data.val();
  var subtype = itemDetail.type;
  var quantity = itemDetail.quantity;
  console.log(subtype + ' ' + quantity);
```

In the first iteration of the forEach of your sample code, itemDetail will be equal to "Farmland" instead of the whole object; thus, subtype and quantity are null. In the new callback, itemDetail will be equal to the whole object, so subtype and quantity can be successfully declared.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: I'll explain further, give me a second.

Comment: I realized one thing, if I change it to var subtype = data.val().type; I managed to get the details, but there is a lot of duplicate. Let's say I got 3 items under bill category, the results printed out are 21 times and I have no idea why is it so

Comment: I have uploaded a picture from my console. The itemKey found are 3 items only, but somehow the console.log in second query is looping for multiple times. It is supposed to print out 3 times only since I only have 3 itemKey

Comment: Exactly! you're accessing the 'data' argument directly, but the forEach is iterating through the whole object unnecessarily; thus, logging extra items. Remove the for loop and it will work the way you want it to.

Comment: I see I see thanks so much! However, after I managed to retrieve, I am storing them into array to be used in the later part. However, from my edited portion, it does not even print out anything. Do you have any idea which part went wrong?

Comment: Where are you declaring datasetarr?

Comment: Sorry my bad, i left it out, I initialized it as array: var datasetarr = [];

Comment: Was it declared inside the function? That's the appropriate scope.

Comment: Yeah it was declared right before the promise. I even do a for loop before the resolve() but still, it does not print out anything also

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean? Because previously I was using the same way for promise to print out some other part of code (just that it is less nested than this one) and it works well.

Comment: You're correct about the promise execution, it should work. Therefore, I still believe the problem is in the array's declaration, which should be inside the promise's construction. Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: Yeap updated edited portion. Yeah I tried to shift it inside the let promise .... but still, nothing was printed out from the for loop inside .then() there.

Comment: Hey I think this should be another question as your suggested answer already solved my first problem. So I opened up another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409078/javascript-promise-not-working-with-resolve

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = firebase.database().ref('receiptItems').child(itemKey);
                      query.once( 'value', data => {
                            var itemDetail = data.val();
                            var subtype = data.type;
                         // you may try data.toJSON().type as well
                            var quantity = data.quantity;
                         // try data.toJSON().quantity
                            console.log(subtype + ' ' + quantity);

                    });
```

In second retrieval you already have access to  receiptItems/itemKey .This is a particular entry in receiptItems , not the whole receiptItems array. 

                                                                         So no need to apply data.forEach() once more as there is only one record. We apply data.forEach() to fetch an array of records/object. In your case it is just one entry.

Comment: I see but after that I am trying to store them into an array as from the edited portion. The problem now is it does not even print out anything

Comment: I think Jorge Bar Mza has answered it . If you still need help ,let me know .

Comment: Cool thanks so much! But do you mind to take a look at the edited portion? Because currently it is not printing out anything

Comment: Hey there is another problem with the promise, I have opened up another thread as my first problem was solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409078/javascript-promise-not-working-with-resolve