# JavaScript promise not working with resolve()

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, asynchronous, promise

I was having some problem with promise in JavaScript. So what I am trying to do is I wanted to retrieve from firebase, then store all the result returned into array. After that I will perform some sorting on the array. Here is my code:

```
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var query = firebase.database().ref('');
        query.once( 'value', data => {
            data.forEach(subtypeSnapshot => {
                var itemData = ;

                var query = firebase.database().ref('').child(itemKey);
                query.once( 'value', data => {
                    var itemDetail = ;
                    datasetarr.push();
                });
            }); 
            resolve(datasetarr);
        });             
    });
```

With this set of code, from the first `console.log` inside the promise, I managed to get these in my console:

With these, it means there is nothing wrong with my firebase retrieval. Afterwhich, I wanted to store each of them into array and this is the part:

```
datasetarr.push({type: subtype, quantity: quantity});
```

After done everything and I resolved the promise, when promise is done, I then print out the items in array. However, nothing is printed out at the for loop inside `.then()`. Any ideas?

Comment: `resolve(datasetarr);` is called before any `datasetarr.push({type: subtype, quantity: quantity});` is run, because asynchronous code is asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned: Your Promise is resolved too early.

You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all promises to resolve before resolving the wrapping Promise. I put together a simple example, however, because of the lack of a firebase database, I just use functions returning Promises: https://jsfiddle.net/57b0gkLt/

According to the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query), `query.once('value')` returns a Promise, so this should work.

**EDIT**: Like this

```
var datasetarr = [];
let promiseItemDataList = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
var query = firebase.database().ref('receiptItemIDsByCategory').child(category);
    query.once( 'value', data => {
        var promises = []; // NEW LINE

        data.forEach(subtypeSnapshot => {
            var itemData = subtypeSnapshot.val();
            var itemKey = subtypeSnapshot.key;

            var query = firebase.database().ref('receiptItems').child(itemKey);
            var promise = query.once('value'); // NEW LINE
            promises.push(promise); // NEW LINE

            promise.then(data => { // .then instead of a callback
                var itemDetail = data.val();
                var subtype = itemDetail.type;
                var quantity = itemDetail.quantity;
                console.log('inside promise ' + subtype + ' ' + quantity);
                datasetarr.push({type: subtype, quantity: quantity});
            });
        }); 

        Promise.all(promises).then(() => resolve(datasetarr)); // NEW LINE
    });             
});

promiseItemDataList.then((arr) => {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        console.log('outside promise ' + arr[i].type + ' ' + arr[i].quantity);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but I got confused by reading the code. So how do I modify it to be applicable for my case? By changing the code inside getQuery() to the part where I retrieve itemKey?

Comment: @DeniseTan See edited post. As I understand the firebase documentation, you can either use `.once('value', callback)` or `.once('value')` which returns a Promise (I hope I'm not mistaken, I never used firebase).

Comment: Sorry but correct me if I am wrong. I am trying to understand how it works. So what you did is declare another array for all the promises in first query. Then, you used the .then to chain with second query and push the data into datasetarr. After that, you go back to the forEach and loop. You check when all promises are done by using Promise.all, at there, then you resolve the datasetarr. Am I right?

Comment: @DeniseTan You have multiple Promises and want to wait until all of them are finished. That's basically the idea of `Promise.all`. Since you do not know how many Promises you will end up with, I created the array and fill it within the `foreach` loop. Then I wait for all the Promises to finish using `Promise.all` and resolve the outer one accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `async` call for retrieving the initial set of data was handled correctly but not the subsequent ones invoked by the `.forEach` loop.

```
query.once( 'value', data => {
    var itemDetail = data.val();
    var subtype = itemDetail.type;
    var quantity = itemDetail.quantity;
    console.log('inside promise ' + subtype + ' ' + quantity);
    datasetarr.push({type: subtype, quantity: quantity});
});
```

Trouble is you're `resolving` the promise before the other async call was returned.

I'm not sure how exactly is `query.once` handling `callback`. It doesn't look like it is doing promises nor the traditional `callback function` way.

What you could do as a `work-around` is to wrap the `forEach.async` calls into a `Promise` object and then fire a collection of promises using `Promise.all([list_of_promises])` to make sure that every single call was returned before `resolving` the main promise.

**Pseudo code:**

```
var datasetarr = [];
let promiseItemDataList = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var query = firebase.database().ref('receiptItemIDsByCategory').child(category);
    query.once( 'value', data => {

        // Collect a list of promises for the sub item async calls
        var get_data_promises = [];
        data.forEach(subtypeSnapshot => {
            get_data_promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve) {
                var itemData = subtypeSnapshot.val();
                var itemKey = subtypeSnapshot.key;
                var query = firebase.database().ref('receiptItems').child(itemKey);

                query.once( 'value', data => {
                    var itemDetail = data.val();
                    var subtype = itemDetail.type;
                    var quantity = itemDetail.quantity;
                    console.log('inside promise ' + subtype + ' ' + quantity);
                    datasetarr.push({type: subtype, quantity: quantity});
                    resolve("Done");
                });
        }))

        // Fire them all - Once done resolve the main promise.
        Promise.all(get_data_promises).done(function() { resolve(datasetarr); });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = firebase.database().ref('receiptItemIDsByCategory').child(category);

query.once('value')
.then((data) => {
    promises =[]
    data.forEach( subtypeSnapshot => {
        var itemData = subtypeSnapshot.val();
        var itemKey = subtypeSnapshot.key;

        var query = firebase.database().ref('receiptItems').child(itemKey);
        p = query.once( 'value', data => {
                    var itemDetail = data.val();
                    var subtype = itemDetail.type;
                    var quantity = itemDetail.quantity;
                    console.log('inside promise ' + subtype + ' ' + quantity);
                });
        promises.push(p)
    })
    return promises
})
.then ((arrayofpromises) => {
    Promise.all(arrayofpromises)
    .then((results)=>{
        console.log(results)
    })
})
```

Comment: But i got an error message stating that data.map is not a function.

Comment: Oh right, firebase has a `forEach` but no map. Maybe the edit is close @DeniseTan